# Cocos2d low image quality

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am now developing a game for iOS .I create a sprite sheet with Texturepacker which produces 2 file .plist and .png file . When I use these files in my code I found that the images of the all sprites have low quality and the color are pale very pale and I think this is because texturepacker program .
Please I want your advise what shall I do to overcome this problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess u didn't change back buffer pixel formate. U can try this.

Used pixel formate kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 instead of kEAGLColorFormatRGB565.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]

                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    //Guru - replaced  kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 / kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
I have changed the code as you told me and I have realized some improvement in the images quality but it still pale .

Comment: @SamehDos, if it is problem with texturepacker, then try with zwoptex.